# How do I delete a channel in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

No, this isn't a duplicate, none of the other solutions I've tried have worked.
I'm trying to make a bot that deletes a channel on command, say, deletechannel, but none of the solutions I've tried have worked. Can I get a full code snippet, with all the first-time stuff? I'm outright puzzled, and the docs haven't been any help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you perhaps include a snippet of the code you have tried, along with any other failed solutions. This will help prevent answers that you have already tried

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We're not here to replace documentation or tutorials, and we're not here to write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `channel = bot.get_channel()` and then `channel.delete()` that should solve your problems

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for.

```
@client.group(name='say', invoke_without_command=True)
async def say(ctx):
    pass


@say.command(name='delete')
@has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def delete_subcommand(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel = None):
    if not channel:
        await ctx.send("You must provide a channel.")
        return
    await channel.delete()
    await ctx.send(f"{channel} has been removed.")
```

You can use this by doing {prefix_of_your_bot}say delete #channel

Answer (score 0):

Using `Greedy` input with `discord.TextChannel` you can get channel objects and after that delete them all.

> [`commands.Greedy`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=greedy#discord.ext.commands.Greedy) A special converter that greedily consumes arguments until it can’t

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.guild_only()
async def deletechannel(ctx, channels: commands.Greedy[discord.TextChannel] = None):
    if not channels:
        return await ctx.reply("Please enter a vailid channel")
    
    for channel in channels:
        await channel.delete()
```

Sample usage `$deletechannel #channel1 #channel2 123456` where 123456 is a channel id